# Approximate solution to a transcendental equation in the limit of a variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, roots, approximation, transcendental-equations

I have the following transcendental equation:

$$2\cot{x}=\frac{kx}{hL}-\frac{hL}{kx}\tag1$$

I would like to inquire whether an approximate solution to $(1)$ can be developed in the limit $h\rightarrow0$.

Some typical values are: $k=16, L=0.25,h=0.001$. Using numerical methods following solutions are obtained for this set of parameters:

`x = 0.00559016, 3.1416, 6.28319, 9.42478, 12.5664, 15.708, ....`

Comment: I am working the full problem. I hope some results soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing notations, you want to find the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\cot(x)-a x+\frac 1{ax}$$ where $a$ is potentially large.

Instead, in order to remove the discontinuities, I prefer to consider the function
$$g(x)=x \cos (x)-a \left(x^2-1\right) \sin (x)$$ Developing as series around $x=k \pi$ and using later series reversion, we have as an *approximation*
$$\color{blue}{x_k=t+\frac{t}{a \left(t^2-1\right)}-\frac{t \left(t^2+1\right)}{a^2 \left(t^2-1\right)^3}-\frac{t \left(t^6-8 t^4-14 t^2-3\right)}{3 a^3 \left(t^2-1\right)^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^4}\right)}$$ where $\color{red}{t=k \pi}$.

Using your numbers $(k=16, L=0.25,h=0.001)$ gives $a=32000$. Let us use only the first and second term since $a$ is effectively very large. The first roots will then be
$$\{0,3.1416037,6.2831904,9.4247813,12.566373,15.707965,18.849558\}$$ which seems to be OK.

Notice that I missed the very small first root because of the transformation form $f(x)$ to $g(x)$.

**Edit**

For the small root, we need a special treatment
$$\cot(x)-a x+\frac 1{ax}=0 \implies a=\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{5 x^2-3 x^2 \cos (2 x)}}{\sqrt{2}}+x \cos (x)\right) \csc (x)}{2 x^2}$$ Developing as series around $x=0$ gives
$$a=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{31 x^2}{45}+\frac{1069 x^4}{945}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Now, series reversion
$$x=\frac 1{\sqrt a} \left( 1+\frac{1}{3 a}-\frac{8}{45 a^2}+\frac{53}{630
   a^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^4}\right)\right)$$ which, for $a=32000$ gives $x=0.005590228174$ while the exact solution is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Thanks for this. This certainly looks a nice workaround to get the approximate roots. But since I am using these roots to build solutions to a boundary value problem, I need the first root. On trying your expression of $x$ with my parameter values (which gives `a=3.2*10^4`), I still miss the first root i.e. `0.00559016`.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. But even after taking all the terms in the new expression you posted, I still cannot get the first small root which is necessary to build the series solution to my BVP. As you mentioned, the transformation you made form $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ lead this small root to drop. Can you give this another try such that the first root is not dropped ?

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks. I even tested the expression in the edit, for a different set of parameters and the results exactly match the numerical result. I just would request, if you could point me to a reference where the concept of *series reversion* (that you mention in your answers) is explained. Really Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra.Have a look at  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Answer (score 1):

When $h \to 0$, the second term on the right-hand side becomes negligible, and the first-term tends to infinity. Hence, the equation approximates the equation $2 \cot x \to \infty$, which occurs when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. Indeed, this is what you see in the numerical solutions: all of them are (very!) close to integer multiples of $\pi$.

Another observation: it depends on which side of zero you are approaching it from! It seems like you are approaching zero from the right, so your roots will always be slightly **greater** than the integer multiples of $\pi$. This is because $\lim_{x \to n \pi} \cot x$ is actually undefined because the limit tends to negative infinity from the left and positive infinity from the right. But when $h$ tends to zero from the right, the right hand side of your expression tends to positive infinity. So the solutions will always lie slightly above the integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: You are right. I too observed the roots being integer multiples of $\pi$. Finding the roots of $(1)$ is part of solving a boundary value problem I am working on. Therefore, knowing the first root (`0.00559016` in the given example) is quite necessary and using the approximation as $x \approx n\pi$ would lead to the neglect of this root (as $n$ starts from 1). Now am I missing something here ?

Comment: No, because actually $ n $ starts at zero: $\cot 0 \to \infty$ when approaching zero from the right.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra I've added another observation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was a really interesting insight. So if I am understanding correctly then, either `0.00559016` is a spurious result *or* it cannot be attained analytically

Comment: @IndrasisMitra No, it's not a spurious result! As from before, we expect a solution right above zero, since $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cot x = + \infty$.

Comment: Ok I understand your point now. But is there a way of getting this root analytically ?

Comment: My method is valid in the limit where $h \approx 0$. In general, exact analytic solutions to transcendental equations are not attainable. There are ways to achieve better approximations (mine is only first order). Claude Leibovici's answer is a way to get a slightly better approximation. But you should only seek more precise approximations if you need them; in many cases this first-order approximation is more than enough.